# Visual Studio 2008 Debugging Windows Embedded CE 6.0 application

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

I'm trying to debug a Windows CE 6.0 embedded application built with the STANDARDSDK_500 (ARMV4I) SDK using Visual Studio 2008. It builds and deploys however when it gets to the stage of starting the application it throws up the error "Unable to start debugging".

I am able to connect to the remote registry so CoreCon is running and connecting OK. I have connected as a "Windows CE Device" using a fixed IP address (although I have also tried dynamic IP address).

At this stage I have no idea what the problem is, I've checked the executable with dependency walker and the only 2 DLL's missing are `COREDLL.DLL` and `WS2.DLL` which are both present on the CE device in \Windows.

I've tried starting the built executable on the device and nothing happens. I have configured the CE device to create dump files but nothing is created.

Any ideas what could be wrong? What I can check next?

Comment: Verify in the project settings that the debugger startup object is the same as the output location.

Comment: I checked that and it is the same. I can see the file is being updated on deploy but it won't start.

Comment: Have you tried a simple "hello world" app?

Comment: A "Hello World" app does start OK. I am convinced this is a DLL link error but I do not know how to prove that. How can I verify the executable is loading all required DLLs?

Comment: Typically CE devices require tailored SDK.

Anyways, compare Compiler and Linker command line options with "Hello World" app.